# How do I use a newer version of r.js with Yeoman build?

Tags: build, requirejs, yeoman, r.js

I'm trying to run `yeoman build` on a project that uses requireJS and the [require-handlebars-plugin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin). I'm am getting this error when running the rjs task:

```
<WARN> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/tkrell/Sites/pathrabbit-marionette-require/temp/scripts/template/schedules/day-jobs    -past.js'
In module tree:
    main
      schedules/schedule-layouts
        schedules/schedule-jobs-view
          hbs

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18)
 Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```

I believe this is the same as [this issue](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin/issues/69) which appears to simply need the latest version of r.js to be resolved. When I use a newer version of r.js manually, I don't get the error and everything works fine. How can I force the `yeoman build` task to use the latest version r.js?

Comment: You could replace the `r.js` file in the yeoman folder, this is located here in Windows: `C:\Users\%USER%\node_modules\yeoman\node_modules\requirejs\bin`. Is this a viable solution? I'm pretty sure they will update the version in a later version of Yeoman.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. I ended up doing something similar to this. I put more details in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The advice given on [the issue I created](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/871) on Yeoman's github page worked for me:

> Yeoman uses 2.0.2 (see it's package.json).
>
> You could go into the directory yeoman is installed and run npm install -f requirejs to force install a newer version. No promises it won't break though.
>
> However, in yeoman 1.0 (which is imminent), we'll be using grunt-requirejs instead.